# Android Explicit Intent, Loading second Activities layout, not reaching OnCreate method

Tags: android, debugging, android-intent, explicit

This is my first android app attempt after reading *"Android 2 Application Development"* and lots of stuff online.

Here is the relevant code:

from MovieRatingsActivity.java   [my main]

```
            Intent i = new Intent(MovieRatingsActivity.this, DisplayMovies.class);

            startActivity(i);
```

from Manifest:

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

        <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMovies"
        android:label="Display Movies" >

    </activity>
```

note: i do not have any intent filters for the second activity.  Do I need any if it is an explicit intent that I never plan on interacting with another application?  I have tried with multiple combinations of different intent filters just out of spite, but its hard to have this answered, as every source I go to jumps to implicit intents and doesn't answer this question.

As for behavior:

Whether in debug mode, or run mode, when I click on the button and create the intent, the emulator switches to the second activity and displays the label at the top, but nothing else.  Worse, in debugger mode, when I try to step-into `startActivity(i)`, it just suspends the main thread and goes no where.  Do you need a special debug technique for when jumping to next activity?

There is a chance that my intents are fine, my logic to display the list is wrong, but even still I would like to be able to reach the code in the debugger.  I also added a `System.out.printline` at the beginning of the second activities `OnCreat`e method that is not executing.

Comment: can you post the code for your second activity?

Comment: how are you sure that the println is not executing? you can post the Logcat messages here, so that we can look for any other errors.

Comment: `System.out.println` does nothing in Android. You should use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html instead

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need any if it is an explicit intent that I never plan on
>   interacting with another application?

you dont need any explicit intents in that case.

> Do you need a special debug technique for when jumping to next
>   activity?

You could put a breakpoint in `onCreate()` of second activity.